# Return List of Students Missing Work

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I have a spreadsheet which I use as a gradebook in class.  I would like to have a sheet which lists each assignment and who has yet to turn in that assignment.

My spreadsheet for grades is on a sheet titled "grades"
The list of missing assignments is to be on "missing"

"grades" is formatted as follows:

[image: http://imgur.com/eKwtg7I]

The result should be that I get in the "missing" sheet

```
Column A - a list of students missing HW 1 which would be Joe, Amy, Lisa, Monty, Pierre
Column B - A list of students missing HW 2 which would be Joe, Bob, Kare, lisa, Monty, and Pierre
Column C - A list of students missing HW 3 which would be Bob, Amy, and Pierre.
```

Help Pls!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(grades!$A:$A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(grades!$A$2:$A$9)/(grades!B$2:B$9=""),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

Copy down and over till you get blanks.

[image]

Comment: I am guilty of up-voting almost all of your solutions whenever I tumble across them. Is there a limit on up-votes for one person per day / week? Someone else told me some time ago that I might get banned if I up-vote someone too much. Sure hope that's not true cause I just love the simplicity and practical approach to most of your solutions.

Comment: What will get you in trouble is the rapid fire upvote of a single person, anything more than four will get reversed the next day. but one here and there as you see them and use them will be okay.

Comment: That is so absolutely perfect.  Thanks a million!  One question, what do the numbers 15 and 6 relate to in the aggregate portion?

Comment: It is the small function that ignores errors, We force errors to skip those we do not want. @EliasGalvan

Comment: @EliasGalvan if it worked for you please mark as correct.

Comment: I know this is probably a stretch for this forum as this is for Excel, but is there a way to translate this to Google Sheets?  Turns out my department would like to be shared through google.  I tried it, but it seems the aggregate function does not exist in google sheets.

Comment: In A2 put `=QUERY(grades!$A:B,"Select A where B is null")` change the B to C for C2 and D for D2.  no need to copy down.  Google will fill in as needed. @EliasGalvan

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks so much, you saved me twice!